# how do you find the non-computed css width with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I know I can use `.width()` and `.css('width')` to get the computed width of an element, but how do I get the value that is set on the element for the width attribute?  This is not the same value as the computed width and I need to know dynamically what the intended width is.

Comment: Do you mean something like `.innerWidth()`?

http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/

Comment: no...that is also computed.  I have <th> tags with style="width:58px" applied with random values set for the width.  The table is not actually displaying those widths since the width of the table is auto.  I need to find value of the style attribute for width.

Comment: Try using .css('width') and moving that inline style to an external stylesheet (and use a class / id)

Answer (score 0):

`style` attributes are changed, once you manipulate it using jQuery. So it cannot be retrieved later on. The best way, I think would be backing up at load if you need it.

```
$(function() {
   var backup = $("#element").attr("style");
   // do others
});
```

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NJYSZ/) to get my point.

Later you can use `.split()` method to extract info like this

```
sp = backup.split(";");
$.each(sp, function(k,v) {
    var params = v.split(":");
    var att = params[0];
    var val = params[1];
    //alert(att+val);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NJYSZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access to stylesheet of the document:

```
var ss = document.styleSheets;

    for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
        var rules = ss[i].cssRules || ss[i].rules;

        for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
            if (rules[j].selectorText === ".classname") {
                //your code
            }
        }
    }
```